# How to execute shell command in new window in ruby/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, sinatra

I have a rails app that needs to start a supporting Sinatra web service. I would like to invoke it via a rake task. But I want the Sinatra app to start **inside a new terminal (command) window**. Yes, I need to see it executing.

```
# rake task
namespace :daq_controller do
  desc "start the DAQ contoller web service"
  task :start do

    dir = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
    sh "cd #{dir}; rackup daq_controller.rb"
  end
end
```

Bonus points if it works on *nix *and* windows

Comment: Opening a terminal window is highly OS specific, though. What "UNIX" are you intending to run this on? Launching a new xterm is easy. Launching a new Terminal.app window isn't.

Comment: Mac: Terminal, Linux: gnome-terminal, Win: ruby already can do this

Answer (score 0):

Linux: gnome-terminal `gnome-terminal --command`

Comment: or --execute CMD ARGS

Same as --command above, included for compatibility.